# Access multiple function of single controller using same router in Laravel

Tags: laravel, function, methods, controller, router

I have a controller That have multiple functions with the same router so I am getting error exception.
Please Guide me for This error

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'admin']], function()
{
    Route::get('/dashboard','DashboardController@chart');
    Route::get('/dashboard','DashboardController@index');
});
```

Comment: You can't call multiple different methods for one single route

Comment: What are you expecting it to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, the solution is :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'admin']], function()
{
    Route::get('/chart','DashboardController@chart');
    Route::get('/dashboard','DashboardController@index');
});
```

Or you can call multiple functions on the same url, one with "get" method, and an other with "post" for example :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['auth', 'admin']], function()
{
    Route::post('/dashboard','DashboardController@chart');
    Route::get('/dashboard','DashboardController@index');
});
```

But the `Route::post()` is accessible only after a form submission with method post.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions